# Why are my form variables not passing through POST?

Tags: php, forms, variables, input, set

I am sending form data through POST, but the corresponding POST variables are not set, and do not.

Also, when I store POST data into local PHP variables, I seem to be unable to use those variables. (Once I resolve the first issue, I have a feeling I will be able to user the variables too.)

My error messages output by the second page (see below) is:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: postUsername in (...somepath)\scripts\create-member.php on line 10
```

(Form page) :

```
<form action="scripts/create-member.php" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name"username" value="" placeholder="User Name"> <br />
        <input type="password" name"password" value="" placeholder="Password"> <br />
        <input type="password" name"passwordConfirm" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password"> <br />
        <!-- ?type email or type text -->
        <input type="email" name"email" value="" placeholder="Email" autofocus> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submitRegistration" value="Register!">

    </form>
```

(Second page) scripts\create-member.php:

```
<?php

//!proper way to declare variables obtained from POST.
// Data from form "register.php"
if ( isset($_POST['username']) ) {
    $postUsername = $_POST['username'];
}


echo $postUsername;    // <-- this is line 10
```

?>

I've tried using isset() for the submit button too, but that didn't solve the problem.
I've simplified the code by a lot here, and ran it testing it too.

Comment: Provide complete HTML? where is the <form> opening tag?

Comment: put your echo inside of `if(isset()){}`

Comment: the form tag was there, but stackoverflow needed me to put in another line break for it to show.

Comment: I tried echoing a literal string. It actually echos nothing.

Comment: Put `=` in `name"password"`, `name"username"`, `name"passwordConfirm"` etc...

Comment: ^ oh my. how embarassing. I knew it would be something like that. I tried checking so many other things, but this is what gets me. thank you for the second set of eyes.

Comment: mods please feel free to close this.

Comment: @gwho5150 A HTML validator would have saved you from this embarassment.

Comment: thank you. im very new. good for that. ill use validator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your html code, you have missed `=` for `name`

```
name="username"
```

Instead of `name"username"`

---

Here's your fixed code.

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="User Name"> <br />
<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"> <br />
<input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password"> <br />
<!-- ?type email or type text -->
<input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" autofocus> <br />
```

Answer (score 2):

the ploblem is not at register.php

you can try to write like this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['username']) ) {
$postUsername = $_POST['username'];
echo $postUsername;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem posting to an index.php file in a folder.

```
<form id="register" name="register" method="POST" action="/register">
// BROKEN
```

all $_POST vars were empty until I added a trailing forward slash to the form post action

```
<form id="register" name="register" method="POST" action="/register/">
// WORKS
```